# Change color of unused variable/imports

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code now greys out unused variable/imports. Is there a way to change the color? As the grey conflicts with the theme I am using.

The theme I am using (Blueprint) uses the same color for object keys.

Comment: As it is a new feature, I don't believe there is a way to change those colors yet - I bet they add a colorCustomization soon though.  I also looked at the scopes of unused variables and there is nothing there that is helpful.  Perhaps there is an extension out there that  helps?

Comment: Did you find anything for this? I find it terribly annoying now as it looks like code I'm working on isn't really code since there is no syntax highlighting...

Comment: @ChristiaanMaks I ended up switching themes to Night Owl, which make the unused imports look a lot more obvious - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sdras.night-owl&WT.mc_id=twitter-social-sdras

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two options:

[image]

and you can change it via `Code > Preferences > Settings > settings.json` like:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorUnnecessaryCode.border": "#0000ff"
}
```

but it does not look well. If you want to achieve a satisfying solution, you can add a new css class into `workbench.desktop.main.css` (that's a hack!):

```css
.monaco-editor.showUnused .squiggly-inline-unnecessary {
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted red;
  color: red;
}
```

It would then look like (`Input` and `router` are unused):

[image: Coloring unused variables]

Unfortunately, you have to look for the file here: `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.css`; it is a part of the official release:

[image]

VSCode shows you a notification after your modification that your installation may be corrupt, but you can ignore this message or fix it with an extension: [Fix VSCode Checksums](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lehni.vscode-fix-checksums).

Comment: If you want to do it properly, maybe the following can help: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide