# un-used variables in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

What would be the setting entry in settings.json that controls the color of un-used variables.

I was playing around with editor.tokenColorCustomiztion entries but with no luck.

Comment: vscode should have a general setting for the editor, shouldn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Change color of unused variable/imports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50930517/2745495)

Comment: you have to look in the semantic color customization

Comment: @rioV8 Which one though?